# menu's text is not fitting small screen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, overflow

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/nwwdboh5/). As you can see the problem lies when you make the Result screen equal to the width of a mobile's screen. Then, the text, instead of changing line, it will be lost (and replaced by dots). Also, you can't even scroll to get it (which would still be bad, but could be a fallback plan).

Here is the actual code:

```
<a href="#popupNested" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" data-transition="slidedown">Info</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupNested" data-theme="none">
    <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" style="margin:0;">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
        <h2>Must save</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
          <li><a href="#" data-rel="dialog">If you don't save, changes won't apply!</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /collapsible -->
    </div><!-- /collapsible set -->
  </div><!-- /popup -->
```

As you can see in the fiddle's comment, I tried to fix that with `data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke"`, which I found on a question about tables, but it didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The code you are using adds the 'ellipsis' to the text on purpose, so I suggest you learn more about jQuery mobile and it's style rules.

Comment: Will keep that in mind @sheriffderek. Which part of the code does that?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. I don't like using stuff like this for reasons like this. Instead of learning the 3 languages - you end up learning a particular set of rules and functions that site on top of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to put a `<br>` tag in the middle of your sentence and set overflow to visible. and text-overflow to clip (the default value). (or initial.) Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/y9sdo79n/) hope this helps!